# Temporarily override config in Rails test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I need to test some Rails code, but for the duration of my test I would like to override some configuration options.

With Python background, I would do this like:

```
def test():
    # ...
    with change_config(key, new_value):
       # do stuff with config changed
    # config is back to old value
```

How would I achieve this in Rails/Ruby?

Comment: Ruby minitest or RSpec? What kind of configuration: a environment variable, a constant, a method?

Comment: You want to redefine a config value across **one specific test, not entire test suite**, am I reading the situation correctly?

Comment: Minitest. A configuration variable, in general; something simpler to setup than a mock. Yes, across a single test, only where invoked.

Comment: Are you talking about a configuration option within Minitest, or at the Rails level, or something else?

Comment: It's a configuration option at Rails level.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
def test
  Rails.config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
end
```

Comment: I would like the old value to automatically be switched back after. I know I can manually do this, but I was looking for an approach similar to what Python can offer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm *not* a ruby specialist, but this is what I came up with. There's probably a more idiomatic way to write it, but it works as is for me.

Wrap the block of code that you want to execute, and override the setting, saving the original value and restore it when the block completes execution.

```
# in `test_helper.rb`
def stub_dev_s3_setting(value, &block)
  original_value = Settings.aws.s3.use_s3_in_dev
  Settings.aws.s3.use_s3_in_dev = value
  block.call
ensure
  Settings.aws.s3.use_s3_in_dev = original_value
end
```

Use in your unit test:

```
it 'overrides setting in dev to use s3' do
  stub_dev_s3_setting true do
    # do stuff with AWS S3 and assert that it worked as expected...
    # when this block of code exits, the original value of the setting
    # will be restored automatically
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Temporary enable a config value in tests:

```rb
before { Rails.configuration.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true }
after { Rails.configuration.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false }
```